# Purchasing a ticket for someone else in another country?

Tags: bookings, lufthansa, egypt, timezones

So this is the first time any of us have ever been through a travel scenario such as this.

Right now, I'm in Egypt with my mother.  We found a trip we agreed on (Lufthansa throughout), but we don't have the money to purchase the tickets, so we reached out to a friend who has agreed to pay for our tickets.  He has to do this online because the local agency at home is more expensive than finding something online.

He should be booking it through Lufthansa.

I need to know what my mother and I need to do on our end when we get to the airport (it's CAI).  Do we just show them the purchase information along with any ticket IDs or whatever?

And as a side question, our departure flight (from CAI) is scheduled for 4AM, meaning this is UTC+2/Egyptian time, correct?

Comment: The time quoted will be local time.

Comment: Times on airline itineraries are always quoted as local time for the location the time applies to, including daylight saving if that is in operation at the time of the flight.

Comment: Must Read: https://www.facebook.com/lufthansa/posts/hi-i-am-booking-tickets-for-someone-else-visiting-from-india-to-ireland-on-the-l/10151581688049004/

Answer (score 12):

Minimally, you will only need your passports, but ideally bring a printed copy of your itinerary that includes the PNR reference.

You can go directly to a check in desk with your passport; there is no need to go to a ticket desk first. As long as your names were correctly entered in the booking the airline can find your eticket from only your name.

Some airports require paper proof of travel at the main entrance, but as far as I remember Cairo is not one of them. Showing a printed copy of your itinerary will suffice if it is.

Departure information is stated at the local time of departure.

Comment: @user: Beware that airlines _sometimes_ demand to have the card that paid for the tickets presented at check-in. I've never had this happen to myself, but there are persistent reports that it happens, perhaps only if the booking trips up some anti-fraud heuristics. You should call Lufthansa and check _well in advance_ whether they will require this.

Comment: @HenningMakholm correct , I know that sri lankan airlines asks for credit card , but they only ask for the number , not proof of the card

Comment: @NigelFds: Hmm, I have difficulty seeing the point of that. If a fraudster books a ticket using a stolen credit card number, he will still know that number when he checks in ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm I expect they make some token charge/hold on the card that proves the holder is able to use it. If the card were stolen when the booking were made, odds are it would have been cancelled by the time the thief went to fly. That being said, if all they have is the long number, that would seem to be difficult.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: a close friend of mine had this happening ~15-20 years ago. French couple, she was in the US (Atlanta, IRRC), he bought a ticket for her (I do not remember if it was domestic or international) on his credit card while he was in France. She needed the physical card, no matter whose name was on it. Yes, it sounds weird, is probably an isolated case but at least this is one data point.

Comment: @HenningMakholm This can happen if the person paying for the flights identifies as one of the travellers on the flight. But it is quite normal that a different person buys the flights to the traveller, for many situations, from family members to business travel. The airline usually has a "the card holder is travelling on the booking" tick box during payment.

Comment: @Calchas: If disabling the anti-fraud requirement were as simple as unchecking a box during booking, fraudsters would all do it, and the check would be worthless. I've seen claims that it only happens for tickets bought online at the airline's own website and not for ones sold through travel agencies (which sounds credible; it would take care of much business travel). But then again I've never been met with such a demand _even_ when doing exactly that.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I assume if the cardholder is not travelling on the booking, the transaction gets flagged for additional review in the risk analysis system. You are right on the second part; the airline is less concerned about tickets sold by its agents because the agent bears the risk for the card fraud.